# React useEffect and setState and setInternal

Tags: reactjs

here is my code:

```
  const [mytime, setMytime] = useState(0)
  const newDate = new Date().toISOString()

  useEffect(() => {
    // create a interval and get the id
    const myInterval = setInterval(() => {
      setMytime((prevTime) => prevTime + 1);
    }, 1000);
    // clear out the interval using the id when unmounting the component
    //return () => clearInterval(myInterval);  
  }, []);

  return <div> {mytime} </div>;
```

when i comment the line of

```
return () => clearInterval(myInterval);
```

`mytime` will add step by 2  and  i cant figure out the reason

Comment: why useEffect‘s function block   run twice

Comment: In strict mode React [runs your effect twice](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#my-effect-runs-twice-when-the-component-mounts) in dev.

Comment: thx i found the official doc ：When Strict Mode is on, in development, React runs setup and cleanup one extra time before the actual setup.

Comment: If you don't clear the interval then when React runs your effect again you have two intervals running, each incrementing myTime every second, which is why it's counting by two.

Comment: Strict Mode is the main reason !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The piece you are trying to comment out is a clean up function. Here you will find more https://react.dev/learn/synchronizing-with-effects#step-3-add-cleanup-if-needed . And 3rd challenge in here https://react.dev/learn/synchronizing-with-effects#challenges is exactly about that.

If I'm not mistaken in my newbie understanding of component lifecycle the steps are the following:

1. Component is initially rendered. React goes through component and creates jsx.
2. After an initial render effect is run (here you create an interval).

Next steps are done in development only (because of React Strict mode)
3. Component is unmounted. And if clean up function is not commented out then interval created after initial render will be cleared and forgotten.
5. Component is mounted again meaning steps 1-2 are repeated.

To summarize, if you skip clean up function you would have created two intervals, both of them increment by one, resulting in incrementing time by two. Don't comment out clean up function, it's crucial piece in here.